# Does a container with less layers run faster?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

If you run `docker build --squash …` It seems the layer history goes `<missing>`. I copied all files from the root volume of builder image to `scratch` image, and they look the same image size.

Is there any performance advantage to have less layers?

Comment: Depends on the backend you're configured to use. There's no universally-true answer.

Comment: ...if you're using an overlay filesystem (like aufs2), more layers will make filesystem traversals slower. If the backend uses hardlinks, reflinks (like btrfs), or a similar mechanism to refer to shared data, it doesn't.